# Can I have a mock service and a backend api in the same api?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to provided a mock service for the users see what the api will return without having to subscribe to it. it is possible?

Comment: Yes you can use Proto-typed APIs which do not require subscriptions

Comment: ok, but when I use prototyped APIs I cant subscribe to the api, even with a backend api developed

Comment: Prototype apis are generally used for testing purposes only. Therefore, after the testing phase is done, you have to publish the api (via api publisher) where users required to subscribe and get a token to invoke the api.

Comment: That's it! thanks!